# ASP.MVC 4 - Using First QueryString Parameter & Append to Action in Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to tidy this url if at all possible.

Curently it looks like this which is returned from an ActionResult GET

```
http://localhost/Controller/Action?City=SomeCity&GeoLat=00.000&GeoLong=-0.00000494
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve

```
http://localhost/Controller/Action/SomeCity?GeoLat=00.000&GeoLong=-0.00000494
```

The City parameter isn't used for anything, so manually editing the first url into the second does indeed return the correct data.

I've even tried appending int the City variable to the action, not really ideal.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}-{City}/",
                new { controller = "House", action = "Location", City = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

Thanks!

Comment: The old URL is still returned from the ActionResult, I suspected that PageList object may have something to do with it  

return View(Views.Location, searchResults.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

Despite removing this the URL is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with the routing change. Add this code BEFORE the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CityRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{City}",
    new { controller = "House", action = "Location" }
);
```

Note that I change the url format slightly and removed the optional parameter part (it's not needed)

Comment: Thanks, it didn't help that my RegisterRoutes method wasn't getting hit!

Answer (score 1):

as I correct understand, this will be solution for you:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "City",
            url: "House/Location/{City}",
            defaults: new { controller = "House", action = "Location" }
        );
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Location(string City, string GeoLat, string GeoLong){  }
```

what is more - you have to add this before default route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

at least, now you will be able to achieve `GeoLat` and `GeoLong` value, as also `City` parametr, in your controller method.

Answer (score 1):

To get the url you're after in MVC 4 you have two options

1. Map a route with a `city` param:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       "City",
       "{controller}/{action}/{city}",
       new { controller = "House", action = "Location", city = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
   ```
2. Rename you `city` param to `id` and use the default route mapping.

(MVC 5 introduces the [RouteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class that allows you to specify mappings on individual Actions.)